# Random that doesn't pull the same value twice unless all values within range were pulled (C#)

Tags: c#

I have an array with values that should be displayed randomly, but I don't want one value to be displayed twice unless all values from said array were already displayed.

This is the code I have so far:

```
//Array of strings that will be displayed
static string[] array1 = { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" };

//Common int rndIndex
int rndIndex;

//Method that runs the random number generator (will be used within other methods)
//There will be one method that will call this method and display the value before the loop
private void runRnd(ref int rndIndex)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    rndIndex = rnd.Next(4);
    textBlock.Text = array1[rndIndex];
}

private void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        //This will check whether user input matches what is displayed, then will call runRnd method again
        bool checkEquals = textBox.Text.Equals(array1[rndIndex], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (checkEquals == true)
        {
            runRnd(ref rndIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: *Can anybody help me?* What is your question?

Comment: Shuffle your array (or its copy) and then select elements one-by-one. This will give you all elements without repetitions in random order.

Comment: What is your problem whit this code?

Comment: Random means anything (= perhaps repeated and perhaps not). What you want is not random, but deterministic with certain conditions. You will have to create an algorithm storing the previously-output values and to cross-checked the given value generated by the `Random` variable against these values in order to decide what to do every time (i.e., keep the generated value or generate a new one). You haven't done anything on this front. What do you expect? Shall we write the whole algorithm for you? If yes, what are our time constraints? You want it right away?

Comment: You could use a list. Get any element with a random value between 0 and Count-1. Then remove the element. And so on...

Comment: @varocarbas yes, that's exactly what I need. I can't shuffle the array, since I'm using at least two (one containing symbols and other containing the answers I expect the user to input) and I need the indexes to match. And I don't want to have a same symbol display twice or thrice in a row while others will not be shown once. I'd be glad if you or anyone could write this for me since I have no idea how to do it, and I have no time constraints, so you could give me this any time. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry if my sarcastic remark wasn't clear enough (-> the right translation is "what on the hell you think that we are doing here? Working for you for free or what?!"). SO is not about writing codes as per your requirements; for that you should consider to hire someone :)

Comment: @varocarbas I honestly thought your offer was sincere, and for that reason I accepted it. If my question bothered you somehow, then I sincerely apologize, as it was never my intent to upset anyone. I merely came here seeking help, since, considering my current knowledge, I am unable to write a code of such complexity. Still, thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: This means that you are not exactly understanding how SO works. Perhaps you should take a look at the help pages (and to other questions/answers). You have posted a clear code and written a descriptive enough question, but you haven't still done anything on what you are requesting (= you plainly expect someone to write a code for you). Your behaviour is off-topic what means that will most likely provoke downvotes/question-on-hold/no answers (I think that some of the answers you got today are not exactly triggerred by your question being objectively on-topic). You are free to behave as wish...

Comment: ... but the outputs will be quite negative for you (and for SO). In any case, sorry if you didn't get my sarcasm (I thought that it was clear; but if you are completely new here, I guess that you don't know this kind of things), because logically the desired output was being properly understood. Hopefully, this episode will help you understand what is exactly expected here, such that you can become a productive member of this community.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your edit ***significantly*** changes the scope and nature of the question.  This is usually frowned upon at SO because it **invalidates** otherwise good answers posted in good faith.  I am going to read it again carefully and compare the edits, but I think I am going to have to roll it back.  (Of course you can ask a new question, and what you really want **is** possible using a shuffle).

Answer (score 2):

Any time you dont want random numbers to repeat, you want a shuffle, because random values *can* repeat.

*I don't want one value to be displayed twice unless all values ... were already displayed*

It doesnt seem like there is much value in the second set/iteration coming up in the same order the second time around.  Random usually means unpredictable, so this will reshuffle the set:

```
Random rng = new Random();
Stack<String> shoe = new Stack<string>();

private void button1_Click(...
{
    if (shoe.Count == 0)
    {
        // refill when empty
        shoe = new Stack<string>(GetNewValues());
    }
    // display next, remove from "deck"
    lb1.Items.Add(shoe.Pop());
}

private string[] GetNewValues()
{
    string[] values = { "value1", "value2", "value3", 
                        "value4", "value5" };

    //simple, usually-good-enough randomizer
    return values.OrderBy(r => rng.Next()).ToArray();
}
```

Using a `Stack` prevents having to keep an index variable around for an array or List.  Getting the next value (`Pop`) automatically uses them up.  When it is empty, it is time for more values.  Alternatively, use the Fisher-Yates shuffle:

```
private void ShuffleArray(string[] items)
{
    string tmp;
    int j;

    for (int i = items.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        j = rng.Next(0, i + 1);
        tmp = items[j];
        items[j] = items[i];
        items[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

For this, `GetNewValues()` would be:

```
...
ShuffleArray(values);
return values;
```

If you *do* want the same order in the second set, you can append the shuffled array to itself:

```
// shuffle or OrderBy, either will work
values = values.OrderBy(r => rng.Next()).ToArray();
// append second set to first
return values.Concat(values).ToArray();
```

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but what is lb1 supposed to be on line 12 of the first code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of the Array?

```
static string[] array1 = { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" };
List<String> list1 = array1.ToList();

int rndIndex;

//Method that runs the random number generator (will be used within other methods)
//There will be one method that will call this method and display the value before the loop
private void runRnd(ref int rndIndex)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    rndIndex = rnd.Next(list1.Count-1);
    textBlock.Text = list1[rndIndex];
    list1.RemoveAt(rndIndex);

    if(list1.Count == 0)
    { 
      list1 = array1.ToList();
    }
}
```

Will create a copy of the Array, remove each value as it used until it is empty, then repeat.

(Not Tested)